# icons not loading when changing apache DocumentRoot "/var/www/"

Tags: php, css, image, apache

I need to load my project directly like this **DocumentRoot "/var/www/cloud"**     and load icons properly.

How to give the proper path in css file?
This is what i have tried so far:

```
background: url(../icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;

 background: url(../../icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;

 background: url(./icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;

 background: url(icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;




    main directory(cloud)
    {

    folder name (cloud/css)
        -custom.css (file name)
        -etc..

     folder name (cloud/icons)
        -fb.png  (image file)
        -twitter.png (image file)
        -etc..

    cloud/login.php
    cloud/signup.php
    cloud/etc

    }
```

Hope you all understand my folder structure.

If i give apache root path like this - `DocumentRoot "/var/www/cloud"` - my icons do not load.

If i give apache root path like this - `DocumentRoot "/var/www/"` - the  icons work great.

in my cloud/css/custom.css:

```
 .social-icons li.twitter a {
     background: url(../icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;

     //here is my problem . how i give the path here any suggestion 
     }
```

but i need load my project directly like this  `DocumentRoot "/var/www/cloud"`     and load icons poperly.

Thanks all.

Comment: `background: url(icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;` should work

Comment: tried not working @Dagon

Comment: where is the icons folder located in `var/www` or `var/www/cloud`? And have you setup your virtualhost yet? or are you accessing the site by `localhost/cloud` ?

Comment: if i give like yours suggestion .when i inspect the element and see the css background url it showing like this http://192.168.1.111/css/icons/twitter.png its wrong path na @Dagon

Comment: my icons folder path is var/www/cloud/icons   and  css path is var/www/cloud/css @SachinSunny

Comment: looks like you have some mod rewrite rules,do you?

Comment: where and which one ? @Dagon

Comment: i didn't get what you coming to ask ? @Dagon

Comment: try `background: url(cloud/icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0; ` . If you haven't set up your virtualhost, your site url will be still localhost. So the image can be accessed at localhost/cloud/icons/twitter.png

Comment: while inspeact element in css part .social-icons li.twitter a { background: url("/icons/twitter.png") no-repeat 0 0; } on hover the url it showing url like this 192.168.1.101/icons/twitter.jpg but load error (console) showing like this GET 192.168.1.101/css/icons/twitter.png 404 (Not Found) totaly confused @SachinSunny

Comment: is there anybody ? help me

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't setup your virtualHost in apache, then your site url will still remain as localhost. So you should try accessing the images with

```
background: url(cloud/icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;
```

You can also setup a virtual host to `var/www/cloud` say port 8001
then you can use the same code `background: url(icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;` and access the site at `http://localhost:8001`

Comment: i already changed my apache httpd  file like this DocumentRoot "/var/www/cloud"  so if i give my server ip address 192.168.1.111 it automatically loading index.php correctly but not loading icons

Comment: what is the error code thrown? is it not found or forbidden? also check your apache error logs. It might be a permission issue.

Comment: if i give like this url(cloud/icons/twitter.png)   in inspect element showing error like this  .its wrong path na GET http://192.168.1.101/css/icons/twitter.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: its pointing wrong path 192.168.1.101/css/icons/twitter.png @SachinSunny

Comment: then try this `background: url(/icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0;`

Comment: tried url(/icons/twitter.png) no-repeat 0 0; not working

Comment: while inspeact element in css part 

.social-icons li.twitter a {
    background: url("/icons/twitter.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

on hover the url it showing url like this http://192.168.1.101/icons/twitter.jpg

but load error (console) showing like this GET http://192.168.1.101/css/icons/twitter.png 404 (Not Found)
totaly confused @SachinSunny